# Ivar error with Fit inside Plot

Tags: evaluation

I'm trying to plot this
`Plot[Fit[med,{1,x},x],{x,0,10}]`
Why this doesn't work? I find out that if I do `Plot[Evaluate@Fit[med,{1,x},x],{x,0,10}]` works fine. But can somebody explain me why this happens in first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Plot` has attribute `HoldAll`, therefore the expression `Fit` is hold in an unevaluated form.

Using

```
Attributes@Plot

(* out *)
{HoldAll, Protected}
```

reveals the attributes

Comment: Thanks, and why this is useful? I mean, the holdall

Comment: Sometimes we don't want the argument to be evaluated at once, please have a look at the examples given by documentation center